# How to perform operation over each dictionary in column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

If I have a column in dataframe with dictionaries:

```
col1
{10:24, 7:3}
{5:24, 1:2, 7:8}
{1:1}
```

How to perform operation of extracting keys from each dictionary for each rows? So I need to get:

```
col1
10, 7
5, 1, 7
1
```

How to do that? `df["col1"] = df["col1"].keys()` doesnt work and I don't know why

Comment: `df['col1'].apply( lambda item: item.keys() )` ?

Comment: or maybe it will work with `.str` (even if you have dictionaries) `df["col1"].str.keys() `

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame` has `.keys()` to get own indexes, not to get keys from dictionares in cells.

But you can use `.apply()` to run function on every elemement in column separatelly.

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda item: item.keys())
```

---

Minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[
   {10:24, 7:3},
   {5:24, 1:2, 7:8},
   {1:1},
]})


df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda item: item.keys())

print(df)
```

Result (now it has tuples with numbers):

```
        col1
0    (10, 7)
1  (5, 1, 7)
2        (1)
```

---

**BTW:**

`DataFrame` has special method to work with strings `.str` which may work also with `list`/`tuples` and some of them even with `dictionary`

It can't get `df['col1'].str.keys()` because `string` doesn't have `keys` but if you use `df['col1'].str[10]` then you get from all dictionares elements which have key `10`

```
0    24.0
1     NaN
2     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

`df["col1"]` is not a dictionary - it is a tuple. That explains why you get an `AttributeError`. You need to iterate over each row in the dataframe column and call `keys()` on it.

```
df['col1'] = [row.keys() for row in df["col1"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.apply` according to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

> Apply a function along an axis of the DataFrame.

Luckily, the default axis is columns, not rows. You are going for a single column, so make your applied function check the current column.

```py
df.apply(lambda c: c.keys() if c.name == "col1" else c)
```